# Use of unassigned local variable 'keyInfo'

Tags: c#, console-application, instantiation

```
Console.WriteLine("Type a number, any number");
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine("Is this your number? {0}", keyInfo.KeyChar.ToString());
```

When ever I try to run this I get the error Use of unassigned local variable `keyInfo` I am just starting out on coding so I decided to make a little game all I need is this last part to work. Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. You are trying to use the variable `keyInfo`, but you never assigned it any value.

Comment: `ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;` this is null you are only declaring it's type but not assigning it a value.. [C# Basics Tutorial - Variables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_variables.htm) here is a good link to keep in your arsenal until you become more proficient in the C# language

Answer (score 4):

It's because you are not assigning any value to `keyInfo`.

Why would you expect to be able to use a value if it has nothing in it?

You need to assign a value to `keyInfo` in order to use it.

Perhaps you meant to do this?

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign the return value to your `keyInfo` variable:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
```

In C#, the `=` symbol is used for assignments.